# Passing int between views doesn't work

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a simple code to take an integer and pass it to the next view but the int always ends up as 0 on the other view.  I know it's not a problem with the variable because it turns out as the real int on the main view.  Here is my code:

```
AnswerViewController *ansViewController = [[AnswerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnswerViewController" bundle:nil];
ansViewController.num = theNum;
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *mainView = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ansView"];
[self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right way to it:

```
//Initialize the storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//initialize the ViewController
AnswerViewController *ansViewController = 
   [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnswerViewController"];
//Assign the value to the controller property
ansViewController.num = theNum;
//Finally present the view Controller
[self presentViewController:ansViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: When declaring ansViewController, did you mean storyBoard instead of storyboard?  Also, you didn't declare mainView here.

Comment: sorry this was a typo , fixed it

Comment: Thanks but for the presentViewController in yours, mainView is undefined.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this crashes the app.

Comment: please post the crash log also try replacing `@"AnswerViewController"` with `@"ansView"`. I am not sure what you have as a storyboard Id

Comment: Oh, that did it!  Thanks, I would vote up but I'm not allowed to yet